# Give mailbox permissions from graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using the Graph API with app permission & with a certificate.

I know how to send emails with the sender which is different from the requestor's email.

I go to admin.exchange.com, select the user and add a mailbox delegation then add the user in "Send as".
My question is how to add user with "Send As" option via Graph API only.

I would like use this method [microsoft permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user?view=o365-worldwide#send-email-from-another-users-mailbox): but from graph api

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this (and all the other Exchange Admin tasks) aren't currently in the Graph API, the only option for doing this programmatically is to use the Powershell cmdlets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps. The good news is that the v2 Powershell module does now support the client_credentials flow https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/modern-auth-and-unattended-scripts-in-exchange-online-powershell/ba-p/1497387